# show a SQL select along with a count of itself?

Tags: sql, count, db2

(Caution: Newbie alert)
I have to put a count of the subsections of a generated view along with the view itself.

Is it possible?

For example, this is the generated view from a SQL select:

```
Client Type      Year
8963   Rural     2012
9044   City      2013
8963   Rural     2014
5145   Rural     2014
5145   City      2012
```

What I want displayed is:

```
Client Type      Year  CountofRural2012 CountofCity2012 CountofRural2013
8963   Rural     2012  1                   1                  0
9044   City      2013
8963   Rural     2014
5145   Rural     2014
5145   City      2012
```

...and so on for all the count permutations.

Comment: You want counts up to the current row? I mean for `8963 Rural 2014` it would show the same as for `5145 Rural 2014` or one less for `CountOfRural2014`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Pio - Rural 2014 is completely separate... so it would show a value of 2 (for line 3 and 4, but wont consider line 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd advise you to look into functions such as pivot.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en

Secondly, if the fields you want to create are known in advance (meaning, you want to create fields for specific years), you can try to sum/count a case field.

```
Select client, type, year,
       sum(case when type='Rural' and year=2012 then 1 else 0 end) countOfRural2012
from YOUR_TABLE
Group by client, type, year
```

Comment: Dougie - when I use your sum/case statement, it gives me an output for each line displayed. I just need a single output as per the OP?

Comment: Oops... sorry... Have you tried using "select distinct" instead of "select"?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Subqueries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) and the [Count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) function. You can wrap a query in another query and use aggregates to count, sum or even do standard deviations on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Ardia,

Here is the way to do it without creating a new table

```
select [Client], [Type], [Year],
(Select COUNT([Year]) From PTable  where [Year] = 2012 and [Type] = 'Rural') [CountofRural2012],
(Select COUNT([Year]) From PTable  where [Year] = 2012 and [Type] = 'City') [CountofCity2012],
(Select COUNT([Year]) From PTable  where [Year] = 2013 and [Type] = 'Rural')[CountofRural2013]
from PTable
```

Here is the live demo https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/397150

Hope it helps.

Just update manually like this after you run above query

```
  Update PTable Set [CountofRural2012] = '' where Client <> 8963
  Update PTable Set [CountofCity2012] = '' where Client <> 8963
  Update PTable Set [CountofRural2013] = '' where Client <> 8963
```

Comment: If the source table is (very) large, or used (very) frequently, this might be a viable option.  Generally, however, it's better to build it on demand.

Comment: HBMirza... is there a way to do this without creating a table? I do not have the privileges to do this.

Comment: HBMirza - I tried that one, is there anyway to get JUST 1 compound answer for each count column? Thanks!

Comment: @Ardia Once after you run the above query just update it manually with a blank space for every client that is not in first row as above. See edited answer